# validate 3 letter month abbreviation input with a regex

Tags: c#, regex, validation, abbreviation

So I currently have this which I believe works but it is quite long. I'm using C# regex.

^(:?J)$|^(:?J)$|^(:?F)$|^(:?M)$|^(?:A)$|^(?:A)$|^(?:S)$|^(?:O)$|^(?:N)$|^(?:D)$|^(:?JA)$|^(:?JU)$|^(:?FE)$|^(:?MA)$|^(?:AP)$|^(?:AU)$|^(?:SE)$|^(?:OC)$|^(?:NO)$|^(?:DE)$|^(:?JAN)$|^(:?FEB)$|^(:?MAR)$|^(:?APR)$|^(?:MAY)$|^(?:JUN)$|^(?:JUL)$|^(?:AUG)$|^(?:SEP)$|^(?:OCT)$|^(?:NOV)$|^(?:DEC)$

Is there any way to make this shorter? I think it is already pretty straightforward but if there is a way to combine what I have here into a shorter regex that is what I am after.

I need it to match the combinations of first letter only, first and second, and all three letters of the month abbreviations.

First Letter only.
^(:?J)$|^(:?J)$|^(:?F)$|^(:?M)$|^(?:A)$|^(?:A)$|^(?:S)$|^(?:O)$|^(?:N)$|^(?:D)$

First and Second letter combinations are matched by this.
^(:?JA)$|^(:?JU)$|^(:?FE)$|^(:?MA)$|^(?:AP)$|^(?:AU)$|^(?:SE)$|^(?:OC)$|^(?:NO)$|^(?:DE)$

Full abbreviations:
|^(:?JAN)$|^(:?FEB)$|^(:?MAR)$|^(:?APR)$|^(?:MAY)$|^(?:JUN)$|^(?:JUL)$|^(?:AUG)$|^(?:SEP)$|^(?:OCT)$|^(?:NOV)$|^(?:DEC)$

Then I combined those regexes into the one I have at the top... which now works as I intend it to However it is still rather huge and I imagine I can be improved.

Comment: Does it need to be a regex?

Comment: if I say the current month is "J", what dos that mean?  What about "M"? Did you exclude "N" on purpose?

Comment: I've updated my post. What I have currently gets a bit closer. Well it does in ruby anyway... it seems to match anything in C#. even ZYB which isn't any of the letters.

Comment: @Mathew does anything need to be a regex? I suspect a regex can do it most succinctly.

Comment: @cb88: replace `|\Z` by `$` which means "end of string" as `^` means "begining of string"

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte I got ride of the | as well as it was causing me to match the end of line.

Comment: I believe what I need to do is split this up so the regex doesn't handle mutiple lengths. So I would have a separate regex for each lenth it may be possible to get this to work as I intend but it is non obvious to me.

Comment: @cb88: the length of the regex pattern is not important and is clearly different of this effectiveness. I will give you in my futur edit a more efficient pattern. you don't need to split anything.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte my point is the letters JFMASOND should be allowed but only as the first letter. And the combinations JA JU FE MA AU SE OC NO DE. The the full abrviations themselves ie JAN FEB... I think I can do those with separate regexs simply and checking length is trivial.

Comment: @cb88: No, it is a bad way. You will not have any advantage to do this. (more test, less efficient). I repeat, don't be afraid by the length of a pattern.

Comment: @cb88: i will give you soon the detail of how the regex engine works.

Comment: @cb88 Such a regex that you have seems very difficult to read and understand, a simple array with a a linq `Any` predicate might be easier to read and debug.  The less number of characters does not necessarily mean more succinct.

Comment: @Matthew I don't doubt that you are right. However the currently regex works and I won't change it unless I have something better... if you have a better alternative I'm all ears. I'm even less familiar with LINQ than regex. Add to that tha LINQ isn't quite portable not that it matters in my case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, i want to inform you that your regex has no sense. Please go [here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) and [here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html) for more informations.

For your problem, you can try this:

```
J(AN?)?|F(EB?)?|M(AR?)?|...
```

or better with non capturing groups:

```
J(?:AN?)?|F(?:EB?)?|M(?:AR?)?|...
```

You don't need to use any character class here, but you can use [alternations](http://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html%E2%80%8E), groups, and [question mark quantifiers](http://www.regular-expressions.info/optional.html).

If you want to match the begining and the end of the string, you can write it like this

```
^(?:J(?:AN?)?|F(?:EB?)?|M(?:AR?)?|...)$
```

For more performances you can use this pattern that use [atomic groups](http://www.regular-expressions.info/atomic.html%E2%80%8E) and [possessive quantifiers](http://www.regular-expressions.info/possessive.html%E2%80%8E):

```
^(?>J(?>AN?+)?|F(?>EB?+)?|M(?>AR?+)?|...|D(?>EC?+)?)$
```

and you can play with the names of months like this for quick fails:

```
^(?>J(?>AN|U[NL]?+)?|F(?>EV?+)?|M(?>A[RI]?+)?|A(?>PR?+|UG?+)?|S(?>EP?+)?|O(?>CT?+)?|N(?>OV?+)?|D(?>EC?+)?)$
```

What the regex engine do? Example with the last pattern:

My example string is `AU` (for AUGUSTUS)

```
 ^(?>             # an atomic group is at the begining of the pattern
                  # In this group there is an alternation J...|F...|M... 
                  # until the closing parenthesis of the atomic groups
 )$               # at the end of the string
```

What the regex engine try:

```
^   ^   # the re is on the begining of the string, all is fine
A   J   # the re try with J and fails then goes to the next alternation
A   F   # test F and fails ...
A   M   # ...
A   A   # test A and succeeds
U   P   # test P and fails and goes to the next alternation
U   U   # test U and succeeds
$   G   # don't test anything the re know that it is the end of the string!
```

Comment: After trying a few inputs I became well aware that it made not sense as it would accept Letters in the wrong order. Heh.. Regex isn't my cup of tea quite yet. I was indeed thinking of something along these lines I just don't have a good feel for the syntax at all.

Comment: @cb88: don't worry regexes are like everything, you will master them gradualy.

Comment: I was able to get it working. Not pretty but it works. If you have any further suggestions you are very welcome to post them however since you helped me get to work I am marking you as the answer. Since you have also pointed me toward better ways to go about this... food for thought!